# ggplot: boxplot with flipped and log transformed coordinates

Tags: r, boxplot

given the following reproducible example

```
ggplot(diamonds, aes(cut, price)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  stat_summary(fun.y=mean, geom="point", shape=5, size=2, colour='black')+
  coord_trans(y="log10")


ggplot(diamonds, aes(cut, price)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  coord_trans(x="log10")+
  stat_summary(fun.y=mean, geom="point", shape=5, size=2, colour='black')+
  coord_flip()
```

it's not clear to me how to transform the coordinates so that to keep the log transformation of the 'price' axis (y flipped);

in fact, after the coordinates flipping the price axis is apparentely loosing the log transformation as a (unwanted by me) side effect;

to be noted that I need that the transforming of the coordinate system occurs after the statistic has been computed, and this is why I used 'coord_trans()' and not 'scale_y_log10()'...

any help for pointing me in the right direction?

thank you

Comment: would it work for your situation to just transform the data before ggplot? and then just forget about the first `coord_trans()` call, so something like `diamonds %>% mutate(log_price = log10(price)) %>% ggplot(..., aes(y = log10_price))` that's what I do when confronted with similar situations

Comment: I would say that is equivalent to the use of either scale_y_continuous(trans = "log10") or scale_y_log10(), i.e. transforming the scale means the data are transformed first,  after which statistics are computed
... but as I said this is not exactly what I want (looking for), thanks

Comment: I see your point (and misread your question a bit). I don't know how to exert that level of control within ggplot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

...oops, very simply switch the aes mappings, drop the flip of coordinates and it's done!

```
ggplot(diamonds, aes(price, cut)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  stat_summary(fun=mean, geom="point", shape=5, size=2, colour='black')+
  coord_trans(x="log10")
```